# How do I put minimized windows to complete sleep (no CPU usage) on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, firefox, cpu, performance, cpu-usage

The title says it all. Basically, I want to stop specific minimized programs in the background from running, for example, a high-CPU program minimized while I work on Firefox. How may I do this on Windows 10?

Answer (score 2):

You can "suspend" applications [using the Sysinternals tool PsSuspend](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/pssuspend) (command line) or using [Resource Monitor](https://ourtechroom.com/tech/why-apps-suspended-windows-task-manager/) or even [Process Explorer](https://www.howtogeek.com/199976/how-to-pause-or-resume-a-windows-application-using-process-explorer/)(GUI).

For PsSuspend:

> Running PsSuspend with a process ID directs it to suspend or resume the process of that ID on the local computer. If you specify a process name PsSuspend will suspend or resume all processes that have that name. Specify the -r switch to resume suspended processes.
>
> **Usage: pssuspend [- ] [-r] [\computer [-u username] [-p password]] <process name | process id>**

Or in Process Explorer you can right click a process to suspend it. (Image from [HowToGeek](https://www.howtogeek.com/199976/how-to-pause-or-resume-a-windows-application-using-process-explorer/))

[image]

Comment: But can you make PsSuspend to suspend an app until you come back to it?

Comment: @redbackspider you can suspend it until you resume it with `pssuspend -r <processName>`.